# NestJS - how to use ConfigService outside NestJS managed class?

Tags: nestjs

I am developing a NestJS project. And here is my project structure:

```
-src
 -config
  -configuration.ts
 -modules
  -auth
  -user
 -utils
  -util.ts
```

In my auth and user module, I import `ConfigModule` and then I can use `ConfigService` to get config values from configuration.ts file.

But how do I get config values in `utils/util.ts` file?
It's just a dir that holds some helper files instead of a module dir.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming that you want the same instance of `ConfigService` to be used... **From a NestJS perspective**, I see two options:

- Group your `util` functions into a single Provider and treat it as a legit component of your NestJS application (or group them by responsibilities, into multiple Providers, this could make more sense too)
- Make your config service available as a node.js module, that you can import "as is" from `util`, and declare as a custom `Provider` from your NestJS app.

Regarding the second option:

```js
// regular typescript class
// exported so you can type your injected "configService" in other classes
export class ConfigService {
 // your code
}

export default new ConfigService();
```

This can be imported as is by `util`.
And injected into your NestJS application by creating a custom provider:

```js
import configService, { ConfigService } from './somewhere/config-service.ts';

const configServiceProvider = {
  provide: ConfigService,
  useValue: configService,
};

// and use it in your ConfigModule
@Module({ 
  providers: [configServiceProvider],
  exports: [configServiceProvider],
})
export class ConfigModule {}
```

When injecting `ConfigService` in your NestJS app, the value will be resolved to `configService` (as long as `ConfigModule` is in the scope, obviously).

**However**, this does not allow your `ConfigService` to inject anything in its constructor parameters... Unless you are ready to use two different instances of `ConfigService` (one for `util`, one for your NestJS app). In this case, you could use a Factory provider, looking like the following:

```js
const configServiceProvider = {
  provide: ConfigService,
  useFactory: (somethingService: SomethingService) => new ConfigService(somethingService),
  inject: [SomethingService],
};

// and in the ConfigModule
@Module({
  imports: [SomethingModule], // so you can inject SomethingService
  providers: [configServiceProvider],
  exports: [configServiceProvider],
})
export class ConfigModule {}
```

Yet this doesn't make much sense, as you would also need the dependencies of `ConfigService` available **out** of the scope of NestJS, in order to use it in `util` functions.

---

An other option (not considering any framework) would be to allow yourself passing (by parameter) the `ConfigService` in your `util`... e.g.:

```js
// old version
export const readDeploymentConfigFile = (filePath: string) => {
  // ...
};

// new version
export const readDeploymentConfigFile = (configService: ConfigService) => (filePath: string) => {
  // ...
};
```

*[This video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZasXwtTRkio) might be inspiring ("Dead-Simple Dependency Injection" by Rúnar Óli Bjarnason, 2012), even if that's not related to TypeScript nor Nest.*

But this is not ideal to use as an API and it might also reveal some design flaws... If your `util` functions need some dynamic/external config values, can we still consider them as `util` functions?

Answer (score 0):

when declaring a config module you can pass an object like that:

```
ConfigModule.forRoot({
  envFilePath: ['.env'],
  isGlobal: true,
  load: [config],
}),
```

this load parameter is a list of functions that return javascript objects which are then added to your configuration, Then you can use ConfigService to get your configuration like that:

```
ConfigService.get("NODE_ENV") //This gets a configuration loaded from .env file

ConfigService.get("mongoose.connectionOptions") //This is a config you setted in app.config.ts for example and return an object containing mongoose connection options
```

your config file may look something like this:

```
var config = {
  app: {
    environment: process.env.NODE_ENV,
  },
  sentry: {
    dsn: process.env.SENTRY_DSN,
    tracesSampleRate: 1.0,
  },
  rabbit: {
    connection: {
      protocol: process.env.RABBITMQ_PROTOCOL,
      hostname: process.env.RABBITMQ_HOST,
      port: process.env.RABBITMQ_PORT,
      vhost: process.env.RABBITMQ_VHOST,
      username: process.env.RABBITMQ_USERNAME,
      password: process.env.RABBITMQ_PASSWORD,
    },
  },
  mongo: {
    user: process.env.MONGO_USER,
    password: process.env.MONGO_PASS,
    dbName: process.env.MONGO_NAME,
    port: process.env.MONGO_PORT,
    host: process.env.MONGO_HOST,
    connString: `mongodb://${process.env.MONGO_HOST}:${process.env.MONGO_PORT}/${process.env.MONGO_NAME}?authSource=admin`,
  },
  mongooseOptions: {
    useNewUrlParser: true,
    useUnifiedTopology: true,
    useFindAndModify: false,
    user: process.env.MONGO_USER,
    pass: process.env.MONGO_PASS,
    keepAlive: true,
    uri: `mongodb://${process.env.MONGO_HOST}:${process.env.MONGO_PORT}/${process.env.MONGO_NAME}?authSource=admin`,
  },
};

var {
  protocol,
  username,
  password,
  hostname,
  port,
  vhost,
} = config.rabbit.connection;
config.rabbit.connection.connString = `${protocol}://${username}:${password}@${hostname}:${port}/${vhost}`;

export default () => config;
```